# Org-mode: A function to org-copy and org-archive unique tasks to different files

Tags: org-mode

Suppose I have two files:

- completed-YYYY.org_archive
- archive-YYYY.org_archive

where YYYY is the current year.

I have an agenda file that looks like this, where each project and task has a unique ID:

```
** My Project
   :PROPERTIES:
   :ID: 1235-48
   :END:
*** DONE Task 1
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ID: 8943-41
    :END:
*** NEXT Task 2
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ID: 0124-47
    :END:
*** Task 3
    :PROPERTIES:
    :ID: 8491-03
    :END:
```

When I go to "archive" Task 1 (because it's DONE), I want the following to happen:

1. Check archive-YYYY.org_archive to see if a "My Project" task with ID 1235-48 exists. If not, copy the contents (not including subtrees) of the "My Project" heading to the file.
2. Check archive-YYYY.org_archive to see if a "Task 1" task with ID 8943-41 exists. If not, copy the contents of "Task 1" and place it under the "My Project" heading.
3. org-archive "Task 1" into completed-YYYY.org_archive.

So when I mark Task 2 as DONE and go to "archive" it, its contents should be copied into archive-YYYY.org_archive under the existing "My Project" task (below Task 1), and then archived as normal into completed-YYY.org_archive.

Is this possible to write a function for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to accomplish something like this using org-id and the code from [here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-08/msg00109.html), which works for my purposes. It may not necessarily be optimized or the best way of doing things, so suggestions for improvements are welcome.

The following code will copy the current subtree into the file you specify, along with that subtree's parents, grandparents, and ancestors. They are assigned UUIDs if they don't already have one, and it won't do anything to entries with the same ID, title, and body contents. If IDs are the same, but the title xor body content is modified, the changes will be copied over. If IDs are the same but both title and body content are different, it will error out just in case.

```
(require 'org-archive)
(require 'org-id)

(defun org-copy-task-hierarchy (filename)
    "This function copies a task/project and its parent hierarchy tree to the given filename"
    (interactive)
    (let ((this-buffer (current-buffer))
          (file (abbreviate-file-name 
                (or (buffer-file-name (buffer-base-buffer)) 
                    (error "No file associated to buffer")))))
        (save-excursion
            ; prepare the target buffer to paste things into
            (setq infile-p (equal file (abbreviate-file-name (or filename ""))))
            (unless filename (error "Invalid target location"))
            (if (> (length filename) 0)
                (setq newfile-p (not (file-exists-p filename))
                      visiting (find-buffer-visiting filename)
                      buffer (or visiting (find-file-noselect filename)))
              (setq buffer (current-buffer)))
            (unless buffer (error "Cannot access file \"%s\"" filename))

            ; construct hierarchy structure and copy current element
            (setq elem-id (org-id-get-create)
                  id-tree (org-copy-task-hierarchy--construct-id-tree))
            (org-copy-subtree nil nil nil t)

            ; move to the target buffer
            (set-buffer buffer)
            (org-mode)
            (goto-char (point-min)) ; move point to top of the buffer

            ; iterate through id-tree to paste in elements if needed
            (setq prev-id nil)
            (while (not (eq id-tree nil))
                (let* ((tree-elem-id       (caar id-tree))
                       (tree-elem-headline (nth 1 (car id-tree)))
                       (tree-elem-contents (nth 2 (car id-tree)))
                       (tree-elem-todo     (nth 3 (car id-tree)))
                       (tree-elem-fullbody (nth 4 (car id-tree)))
                       (target-location    (org-id-find-id-in-file tree-elem-id (buffer-file-name))))
                    (if (eq target-location nil) ; id doesn't exist
                        ; insert elem-fullbody
                        (progn 
                            (if (eq prev-id nil)
                                (goto-char (point-max)) ; move point to end of buffer
                              (setq prev-location (org-id-find-id-in-file prev-id (buffer-file-name)))
                              (unless prev-location 
                                (error "ERROR: Could not find id %s in file %s" prev-location buffer-file-name))
                              (goto-char (cdr prev-location))
                              (org-end-of-subtree t t)) ; move point after subtrees of previous entry 
                            (insert tree-elem-fullbody)
                            (save-buffer)) ; needed for org-id-find-id-in-file to find newly added IDs

                        ; id already exists, check for what's different
                        (goto-char (cdr target-location)) ; move point to target
                        (let* ((target-id (org-id-get))
                               (target-headline (org-get-heading t t))
                               (target-contents (org-get-entry-no-subtrees t))
                               (target-todo     (org-get-todo-state))
                               (match-headline-p (equal target-headline tree-elem-headline))
                               (match-contents-p (equal target-contents tree-elem-contents))
                               (match-todo-p     (equal target-todo tree-elem-todo)))
                            (if (or (and match-headline-p match-contents-p (not match-todo-p) 
                                         ;(equal tree-elem-todo "DONE") (equal tree-elem-todo "COMPLETE"))
                                         (member (tree-elem-todo) org-done-keywords))
                                    (and match-headline-p (not match-contents-p))
                                    (and (not match-headline-p) match-contents-p))
                                ; update target element with tree element
                                (org-replace-full-entry tree-elem-fullbody)
                                ; check if neither title nor contents match
                              (when (and (not match-headline-p) (not match-contents-p))
                                  (error "ERROR updating id %s - 
                                          title and body too different from existing" tree-elem-id)))))
                    (setq prev-id tree-elem-id))
                ; headers, content, todo state are all same; skip and go to next elem
                (setq id-tree (cdr id-tree)))

            (when (not (eq this-buffer buffer))
                (save-buffer))
            (message "Subtree copied %s" (concat "in file: " (abbreviate-file-name filename))))))

(defun org-copy-task-hierarchy--construct-id-tree ()
    "Construct and return a list/tree containing the IDs and content of the hierarchy"
    (let ((id-tree nil))
        (save-excursion
            (while (org-up-heading-safe)
                (org-back-to-heading t) ; set point to heading beginning
                ; get current element's headline, content, and TODO state
                (setq elem-id       (org-id-get-create)
                      elem-headline (org-get-heading t t)             ; ignore todo and tags           
                      elem-contents (org-get-entry-no-subtrees t)  ; ignore properties
                      elem-todo     (org-get-todo-state)
                      elem-fullbody (org-get-full-entry))
                ; build id tree in reverse in order
                (if (eq id-tree nil)
                    (setq id-tree (cons (list elem-id elem-headline elem-contents elem-todo elem-fullbody) nil))
                  (setq id-tree 
                      (cons (list elem-id elem-headline elem-contents elem-todo elem-fullbody) id-tree)))
                ))
        ; append current element to tree
        (setq id-tree (nconc id-tree (cons (list (org-id-get-create) 
                                                 (org-get-heading t t) 
                                                 (org-get-entry-no-subtrees t) 
                                                 (org-get-todo-state) 
                                                 (org-get-full-entry)) nil)))
        id-tree))

(defun org-get-full-entry ()
    "Get the entry text, including heading, no subtrees. 
     If no-properties is non-nil, ignore the text properties of the entry"
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion 
        (let (beg end)
            (org-back-to-heading t) ; set point to heading beginning
            (setq beg (point))
            (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n")
            (save-match-data (outline-next-heading)) ; move point to next heading line
            (setq end (point))
            (goto-char beg)
            (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))))

(defun org-get-entry-no-subtrees (&optional no-properties)
    "Get the entry text, after heading, no subtrees. 
     If no-properties is non-nil, ignore the text properties of the entry"
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion 
        (let (beg end)
            (org-back-to-heading t) ; set point to heading beginning
            (setq beg (point-at-bol 2))
            (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n")
            (save-match-data (outline-next-heading)) ; move point to next heading line
            (setq end (point))
            (goto-char beg)
            (if no-properties
                (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end)
              (buffer-substring beg end)))))

(defun org-replace-full-entry (&optional text)
    "Replace the entry text, including heading but excluding subtrees, with the given text. 
     If text is nil, simply delete the entry text."
    (interactive)
    (save-excursion 
        (let (beg end)
            (org-back-to-heading t) ; set point to heading beginning
            (setq beg (point))
            (skip-chars-forward " \t\r\n")
            (save-match-data (outline-next-heading)) ; move point to next heading line
            (setq end (point))
            (goto-char beg)
            (delete-region beg end)
            (when text
                (insert text)))))
```

To handle the archiving part, we can make use of the above functions in another one:

```
(defun archive-log ()
    "Copy current subtree and ancestors to archive.org_archive, then archive to completed.org_archive"
    (interactive "P")
    (org-copy-task-hierarchy 
        (concat "./archive-" (format-time-string "%Y%m" (current-time)) ".org_archive"))
    (org-archive-subtree-default))
```